# How to create connected modal forms with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-bootstrap

I want have a table showing a list of students. When a user clicks on a one of these students, a modal form pops up showing the details of the student (this works fine). I expose the selected student to the modal control using resolve like below:

```
function showStudentDetails(){
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'tpl/student/app_student.view.html',
            controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance, selectedStudent){
                $scope.selectedStudent = selectedStudent;
                $scope.userClickedCancel = function(){
                    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                }
                $scope.userClickedEdit = function(){
                    $uibModalInstance.close(selectedStudent);
                    modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedStudent){
                        showStudentEdit(selectedStudent);
                    })
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                selectedStudent: function() {
                    return $scope.selectedStudent;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Now, in this modal form there's an edit button which open a second modal.The second modal opens up fine and this is done by the

```
$scope.userClickedEdit = function(){
                $uibModalInstance.close(selectedStudent);
                modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedStudent){
                    showStudentEdit(selectedStudent);
                })
            }
```

in the first code snippet. The problem is the `selectedStudent` is not available in the context of my second modal form so the edit form input controls are blank. Below is my second modal form.

```
function showStudentEdit(selectedStudent){
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'tpl/student/app_student.edit.html',
            controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance, selectedStudent){
                $scope.selectedStudent = selectedStudent;
                $scope.userClickedCancel = function(){
                    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                selectedStudent: function(){
                    return selectedStudent;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks for taking time to check this and appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Could you write a plunkr reproducing the problem? I would move the `modalInstance.result.then(...)` to the bottom of the `showStudentDetails()showStudentDetails()` function, though.

Comment: @JBNizet - Thanks for validation of the snippet. Just realised that I have been referencing the selectedStudent attribute by some other name in the view... Sorry to waste your time.